# Django timestamp is wrong

Tags: django

**Can the Timezone match where ever the user is logging in from?**

```
{{ surveyset.added }}
```

is printing April 9, 2014, 6:20 a.m.

But I did not add the object at that time.

```
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My server time is correct:

```
$ date
Tue Apr  8 23:24:13 PDT 2014
```

Is there a django timezone setting I am missing somewhere?

Do I just need to use `pytz`? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: have you changed [TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_TZ = True
```

Make sure these settings are set in `settings.py`.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones

Check out that link for more info.